# How to determine minimal Eclipse plug-in requirements?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, environment, minimum-requirements

I've built an Eclipse plug-in. Currently I have specified the minimum execution environment as *JavaSE-1.7*. This is the environment the plug-in has been written in.

Is there any way to determine the *actual minimum version* for my plug-in?

Comment: Set the source compatibility level of the plugin projects to 1.6 and see if it blows up? But honestly, I don't think you can get Java 1.6 any more, so 1.7 seems a reasonable "minimum" to me.

Comment: Unless you have actual older versions to compile against, you can't do anything but check every method call and double-check when it was added to the API.